# Expand/collapse div on hover - not collapsing when not active

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have some divs set up so they expand when you hover on them, but at the moment they aren't closing when you don't hover on them, it just stays on the last one you hovered on. How can I get it so they are all closed if you aren't hovering on one?

JS

```
   function hoverTiles(){
        var tiles = $('.button');
        tiles.removeClass('active');
        tiles.hover(function(){
            tiles.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        })
    }

$(document).ready(function() {

    hoverTiles();

  })
```

CSS

```
.buttons .button h4 { 
    z-index:3;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 5%; 
    left: 5%; 
    width: 82%; 
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.buttons .button {
  display: inline-block;
position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 32%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
}
.buttons .button span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 54px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
}
.buttons .button h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: grey;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
}
.buttons .button p {
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: grey;
}
.buttons .button p a {
  color: #1489ff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.buttons .active {
  width: 32%;
  height: 100%;
}
.buttons .active span {
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  font-size: 81px;
}
.buttons .active p {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.25s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.buttons .active h4 {
  margin-top: 15px;
display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="buttons">

    <div class="button active">
        <span><i></i></span>
        <div class="header">
        <img src="/pageassets/test.jpg" alt="" />
        <h4 style="color:black;">Documents</h4>
        </div>
        <ul>    
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give a jsFiddle link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hover` can take a second function as a parameter which adds a handler for when the mouse leaves the element. You could remove the class again in there:

```
tiles.hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass('active');
}, function() {
   $(this).removeClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);
```

Its example from https://api.jquery.com/hover/

You can also use mouseover() and mouseout() if you want to do that differently.